# Need to get the result of query combining the databases and its collections

Tags: mongodb

I am new to Mongodb and need some help ( as below )

**Database: Test1**

*Collection Name* : info_123

```json
{"_id" : ObjectId("5e975401c0178289eb6ac88a"),
    "name" : "hello_123",
    "model" : "omni",
    "status:true"
}
```

*Collection Name* : info_abc

```json
{"_id" : ObjectId("5e975401c0178289eb6ac08a"),
    "name" : "beta_a",
    "model" : "aqua",
    "status" :"true"
}
```

**Database:Test2**

*collection name : info_A*

```json
{"_id" : ObjectId("5e975401ce178289eb6ac88a"),
    "name" : "hello_123",
    "model" : "aqua",
    "status" :"false"
}
```

*Collection Name : info_B*

```json
{"_id" : ObjectId("5e975401c0178289ebsac08a"),
    "name" : "alpha_123",
    "model" : "aqua",
    "status" :"false"
}
```

*Collection Name : Beta_B*

```json
{"_id" : ObjectId("5e975401c0178289ebsac08a"),
    "name" : "alpha_123",
    "model" : "aqua",
    "status" :"false"
}
```

**Problem** : Need the query across all the databases(test1,test2 etc) where collection name is like "info_" and "name" field in that collection should not contain "hello" and then group by "model" field and status is "True".

```js
    db = db.getSiblingDB("admin");
    dbs = db.runCommand({ "listDatabases": 1 }).databases;
    
    // Iterate through each database and get its collections.
    dbs.forEach(function(database) {
        db = db.getSiblingDB(database.name);
        cols = db.getCollectionNames().filter(?);
    
        // Iterate through each collection.
        cols.forEach(function(col) {
            
        // Do something with each collection.
            print(col);
        });
    sudo
    });
```

Comment: what is your problem now? you somehow answered your question.

Comment: @Ashkan : the above query is incomplete . I am not able to do the group by condition.

Comment: You can write your code in JS and then call it from the shell. Take a look at this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39748101/how-to-get-list-of-databases-in-mongodb-using-nodejs

Comment: @Ashkan : Please go through the problem

Comment: Basically in the above query only 1 record     "name" : "beta_a",
    "model" : "aqua",
    "status" :"true"
} should be displayed

Answer (score 0):

You can get the name of the databases like this:

```
const infoReg = /^info_/;
db.getMongo().getDBNames().forEach(dbName => {
    const siblingDb = db.getSiblingDB(dbName);
    const collectionList = siblingDb.getCollectionNames().filter(collectionName => {
        if (collectionName.match(infoReg)) {
            return true;
        }
    });
    // db.getCollection(collectionList[0]).find({});
    print(collectionList);
});
```

By Regex you can find the collection that has your criteria.

Comment: I tried your query and i also tried query as below  dbs.forEach(function(database) {
    db = db.getSiblingDB(database.name);
    cols = db.getCollectionNames().filter(function(col){return col.match(/info/i)}) 

    // Iterate through each collection.
    cols.forEach(function(col) {
        
    // Do something with each collection.
        print(col);
    });

});

Comment: for eg db.getCollection('Info_992d0537-da97-48fc-bd3c-40e6e03055ab').aggregate([
    {"$match"{{$not:{name:/hello/i},status:{$eq:"true"}},
 {"$group" : {_id:{source:"$model"}, count:{$sum:1}}}
])

Comment: I ran this query on the exact same database situation that you explained in the question. Really can not help more. @dhairya

Comment: thanks @ashkan  but where should i add this bit to get the desired result.  :  {"$match"{{$not:{name:/hello/i}, status:{$eq:"true"}}, {"$group" : {_id:{source:"$model"}, count:{$sum:1}}} ])

Comment: The match that I wrote is pointing to Regex, not to the MongoDb. Write the above lines step by step and use `print` to get the answer and extend it. Maybe it helps you. 
collectionList contain the name of the collection with your mentioned criteria. @dhairya

Comment: If you want to get a query on each collection, do your query before `print`.