# Print the names of collections with mongoDB and node.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb

im using mongoclient and im sure that I have connection to the database

```
const client = new MongoClient(uri);
const datatbaseslist = client.db().admin().listDatabases();
    datatbaseslist.databases.forEach(db => {
        console.log($db.name)
    });
```

I saw that code in a video of the mongodb and its not working.
thanks

I have tried looking for other versions to that line

```
const datatbaseslist = client.db().admin().listDatabases();
    datatbaseslist.databases.forEach(db => {
        console.log($db.name)
    });
```

because im pretty sure that the problem is there.

Comment: Try `client.db.admin().listDatabases()` or `db.adminCommand( { listDatabases: 1 } )` See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39748101/how-to-get-list-of-databases-in-mongodb-using-nodejs

Comment: listDatabases() returns a Promise, so you should either await it or pipe to .then()

Comment: You are using `db` in the function parameter but you're using `$db` in the console log. Also, it'd help if you share the error you're getting

Answer (score 1):

I think your question title is saying one thing (collections) and your code is confusing this any another (databases).

- A mongodb server can have multiple databases.
- A database can have multiple collections.
- You connect to the server using a client.
- Normally if you want to know about the databases, you would use `admin()`. Or to connect to a specific database (although you can connect via URI), the you use `db(dbName)` from the client.
- Once you have a db object, you can get the collections from there.

The below code shows you how to get both databases and collections.

```
const { MongoClient } = require('mongodb')

async function main () {
  // Set config
  const uri = 'mongodb://localhost:27017'
  const client = new MongoClient(uri)

  try {
    // Connect to the MongoDB cluster
    await client.connect()

    // Get databases
    const databasesList = await client.db().admin().listDatabases()
    for (const dbName of databasesList.databases.map(db => db.name)) {
      console.log('DB:         ', dbName)

      // Get collections for each database
      const collections = await client.db(dbName).listCollections().toArray()
      console.log('Collections:', collections.map(col => col.name).join(', '))
      console.log('---------------------------------------------')
    }
  } catch (e) {
    // Handle any erros
    console.error(e)
  } finally {
    // Always close the connection to the database when finished
    await client.close()
  }
}

main().catch(console.error)
```